# Qt - How to get a string between 2 character?

Tags: regex, qt

I am working on Qt using string. How can I get a string between 2 characters are '#' and ':'

my strings below:

```
#id:131615165

#1:aaa,s1

#23:dd

#526:FE
```

the result that I want to get is: "id", "1", "23", "526".

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: There's a saying going something like this: A programmer had a problem. He decided to solve it using regular expressions. Now the programmer have *two* problems. A regular expressions is a powerful tool in the right situation, but also very complex and prone to introducing bugs. In your case, you could simply find the position of the `':'`, then get the sub-string up to that position, and skip the first character (the `'#'`). It's simple and easy to write and debug.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution using [`QRegularExpression`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qregularexpression.html):

```
QRegularExpression regex("^#(.+?):");
qDebug() << regex.match("#id:131615165").captured(1);
```

#### Pattern explanation:

- `^` matches the start of a line
- `#` matches the **#** character
- `(.+?)` is a capture group where:

  - `.` matches any character except line terminators
  - `+` matches one or more characters
  - `?` is a "lazy" match to handle situations where multiple colons are present in the string.
- `:` matches the **:** character

Comment: why are you posting twice?... please, next time consider editing the answer instead of re posting the same answer....

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend an online regex-tester to start with the regex, for example: https://regex101.com

Using the following code you can capture the data from a QString:

```
QString input = "#id:131615165";
QRegExp test("#(.*):");
if(test.exactMatch(input))
{
    qDebug() << "result:" << test.cap(1);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, a warning is unknown escape sequence '\#' appear

Comment: Sorry my bad, post has been edited by removing the extra slash (was copied wrongly from regex101.com)

Answer (score 2):

`QString` based solution:

```
QString s("    #iddfg:131615165");
int startPos = s.indexOf('#') + 1;
int endPos = s.indexOf(':');
int length = endPos - startPos;
qDebug() << startPos << length << s.mid(startPos, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Someprogrammerdude wrote in the comments:

```
QString getTag(QString const &input)
{
    QString result;
    int idx = input.indexOf(':');
    if(input.startsWith('#') && idx > 1) {
        int len = idx - 1;
        result = input.mid(1, len); // [0]='#', [idx]=':'
    }
    return result;
}
```